# How to select End date automatically after selecting startdate in Bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, momentjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

```
$('#Startdate').daterangepicker({
    singledatepicker=true,
    locale:{Format : "dd-mm-yyyy"}
});

$('#Enddate').daterangepicker({
    singledatepicker=true,
    locale:{Format : "dd-mm-yyyy"}
});
```

In UserInterface I have two Text box `@html.EditiorFor(m=>m.Startdate)` and `@html.EditiorFor(m=>m.Enddate)`.

How can we change when we select date from startdate and enddate automatically shown end date of that month ? I am also unable to show current textbox date in daterangepicker to highlight. any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean with _show current textbox date in daterangepicker to highlight_?

Comment: I mean to say that, if textbox have date 12/09/2017 , but daterangepicker is showing with 06/09/2017 highlighted in calendar.

Comment: @VincenzoC :Please help, its very urgent for me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $('#Startdate').daterangepicker({
               singledatepicker=true,
               locale:{Format : "dd-mm-yyyy"},  
       onSelect: function(selectedDate) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); 
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("setDate", date);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date); 
     }
    });
```

Comment: Some comments would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a callback function when you init `daterangepicker`. The callback gets the selected date as input and you can [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) 15 days using momentjs (one of components dependencies). Then you can use daterangepicker `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` [methods](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) to set the value on `#Enddate`.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#Startdate').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  locale:{format : "DD-MM-YYYY"}
}, function(start, end, label){
  if( start ){
    var end = start.clone().endOf('month');
    $('#Enddate').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(end.startOf('day'));
    $('#Enddate').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(end.endOf('day'));
  }
});

$('#Enddate').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  locale:{format : "DD-MM-YYYY"}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input id="Startdate">
<input id="Enddate">
```

Please note that you have to provide a valid object as parameter of `daterangepicker` function. Do not use `singledatepicker=true`, and pay attention to capitalization, the valid options for the daterangepicker are `singleDatePicker: true` (camel case) and `format` (lowercase).

Comment: sorry for typo error singledatepicker=true . but its not working.

Comment: @user3085836 what is not working? Do you see any issue with the snippet?

Comment: @ VincenzoC : i am getting, unable to get property "setStartDate" of undefined or null reference.

Comment: @ VincenzoC : sorry my bad. this code is working, thanks. i have one more que how to select  month end date like for sep 30 or 31 oct.

Comment: i am using 
    moment().add('months',1).date(0) but i showing always end date of current month.

Comment: @user3085836 you can use [`endOf('month')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) to get the end of the month using momentjs.

Comment: i already tried with endof('month') 
    $('#Enddate').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(endof('month')); its not changing the end date according to start date, throwing the exception endOf not defined.

Comment: You have to call `endOf('mont‌​h')` on moment objects, for example you can do `$('#Enddate').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment().endOf('mont‌​h'));` to set the value to the last day of the current month. Please do not post new question on comments, ask a new one or edit it (if you have to add relevant details).

Comment: @ VincenzoC Thanks. i have edited  the question. i tried your suggestion but i am getting exception object doesnot support property or method 'endOf'

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#StartDate').daterangepicker({
            singleDatePicker: true,
            locale: { format: "DD-MM-YYYY" }
        },
         function (start, end, label) {
             var selectedDate = start._d;
             var EndMonthDate = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
             EndMonthDate = EndMonthDate .getDate() + '/' + (EndMonthDate .getMonth() + 1) + '/' + EndMonthDate .getFullYear();
             $('#EndDate').daterangepicker({
                 singleDatePicker: true,
                 startDate: EndMonthDate 
             });
         });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#Startdate').daterangepicker({
               singledatepicker=true,
               locale:{Format : "dd-mm-yyyy"},  
       onSelect: function(selectedDate) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate"); 
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("setDate", date);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#Enddate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date); 
     }
});
```

Comment: Please when you answer also add a small explanation of what your code is doing and how it will solve the asker problems